# distinguishing community from society

Tags: vocabulary

2) A definite geographical area is not necessary for society. It is universal and pervasive; but, a definite geographical area is essential for a community.

Regarding the explanation above, when we say the following, after all I am wondering which geographical area is to be considered. That is, I can not see any area, however, Could you??

The academic community

[enter link description here](http://www.preservearticles.com/201104306147/7-most-important-differences-between-society-and-community.html)

Comment: I'd recommend you to avoid using the definitions you found on the page you linked to in other contexts. What discussed in *[7 most important differences between society and community](http://www.preservearticles.com/201104306147/7-most-important-differences-between-society-and-community.html)* seems to be in the context of Community of India and Indian Society from the viewpoint of laws in India.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't think of a defined geographical area for "academic community" is that there isn't one. The term "community" is not restricted to people living in a defined geographical area; that's a part of one definition of the word, but there are other definitions that are more about shared characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

That definition is only correct if you are referring to concrete communities, such as a neighborhood. More abstract communities don't need a geographical location. The word 'community' implies that its members are linked together through a shared interest or belief, and that it is separate from the larger group. Within a 'society', you will find many 'communities'.

Think of a 'society' as a school and a 'community' as your field of study within the school: one is always smaller than the other, and so you are more familiar with the people in the smaller group.